# SNMP get mac addresses connecting to switch ports

Tags: string, snmp

I run snmpwak -v2c -c public switchname .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1 as per instrucion in http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk362/technologies_tech_note09186a00801c9199.shtml.
I got lots of Hex-String and String.

Hex-STRINGs like this:

```
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.1.244.109.4.97.116.234 = Hex-STRING: F4 6D 04 61 74 E0
```

STRINGs like these:

```
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.1.44.39.215.46.139.92 = STRING: ",'×.<\\"
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.1.44.39.215.46.142.98 = STRING: ",'×.Zb"
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.1.44.39.215.46.145.38 = STRING: ",'×.'&"
```

Some Macs can be found in Hex-STRING, but others can't. Maybe are some Macs hidden in STRING? How can I convert these STRING to HEX?

Answer (score 2):

The six decimal values in the MIB after mib-2.17.4.3.1.1 is indeed the MAC address in decimal form.

```
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.1.44.39.215.46.139.92

44 (2c) 39 (27) 215 (d7) 46 (2e) 139 (8b) 92 (5c)

2c:27:d7:2e:8b:5c  OUI search: HP
```